# download multiple pdfmake file using jsZIP

Tags: javascript, python, pdfmake, jszip

I am using PDFmake in my django project to generate pdf files. I want to download multiple files using one button clicked. That's why I planned to use jsZIP to download all the file in a zip format.

```
function downloadAllPayslip(){
      var employeeIdLst = getSelectedPayslipEmployeeIds();
      $.ajax({
        type: 'GET',
        url: '{% url "salary:ajax-download-all-payslip" %}',
        data: {
            'month': dateVar.getMonth()+1,  // number
            'year': dateVar.getFullYear(),
            'employee_id_lst': JSON.stringify(employeeIdLst),
        },
        dataType: 'json',
        success: function (data) {
          var lastDay = new Date(dateVar.getFullYear(), dateVar.getMonth() + 1, 0);
          var lastDayStr = lastDay.toString("MM/dd/yyyy");
          var lastDayStrSplit = lastDayStr.split("/");
          var monthName = months[parseInt(lastDayStrSplit[0]) - 1];
          var monthNameS = monthName.slice(0, 3);
          var year = lastDayStrSplit[2];
          var day = lastDayStrSplit[1];
          var zip = new JSZip();
          var bufferPDFList = [];
          var docDefinitionArr = [];
          var docDefinitionBufferArr = [];
          var content;
          var dataPDF;
          var nameArr = [];
          for (var i = 0; i < data.length; i++) {
            // Employee info
            var dailyStartTime = moment(data[i].daily_start_time, 'HH:mm:ss').format('h:mm A');
            var dailyExitTime = moment(data[i].daily_exit_time, 'HH:mm:ss').format('h:mm A');

            var employeeId = data[i].e_id;

            var employeeName = data[i].name;
            nameArr.push(employeeName);
            var employeeType = data[i].type;
            var employeeDesignation = data[i].designation;
            var employeeDepartment = data[i].department;
            var employeeJoinDate = data[i].join_date;
            var weekends = data[i].weekends;
            var shift = dailyStartTime + ' - ' + dailyExitTime;
            var breakDuration = data[i].break_duration;

            var leaveBalanceDict = data[i].leave_balance_dict;
            var leaveDataDict = []
            for (var leaveType in leaveBalanceDict) {
              var leaveDict = leaveBalanceDict[leaveType];
              var total = leaveDict.total;
              var taken = leaveDict.taken;
              var accrued = leaveDict.accrued;
              var remained = accrued - taken;
              leaveDataDict.push({
                'Leave Types': leaveType,
                'Leave Entitled(days)': total,
                'Leave Taken(days)': taken,
                'Leave Accrued(days)': accrued,
                'Leave Remained(days)': remained
              })
            }


            // Salary details
            if (data[i].is_overtime) {
              var overtimeAddition = data[i].overtime_addition + ' (+' + formatHHMM(data[i].overtime_hour) + ')';
            }
            else {
              var overtimeAddition = 'N/A';
            }

            var basicPay = data[i].basic_salary;
            var overtimePay = overtimeAddition;
            var lessWorkDeduction = data[i].less_work_deduction + "(" + formatHHMM(data[i].work_hour_deficit) + ")"
            var unpaidLeaveDeduction = data[i].unpaid_leave_deduction + "(" + data[i].unpaid_leave_count + "days)"
            var additionalPay = data[i].salary_addition;
            var totalPay = data[i].total_salary;
            var taxDeduction = data[i].tax_deduction+ "(" + data[i].percent_tax + "%)";
            var netSalary = data[i].net_salary;
            var comment = data[i].comment;

            var companyName = '{{ company_name }}'
            // Generate pdf
            var docDefinition = {
              footer: function(currentPage, pageCount) {
                return {
                  columns: [
                    {
                      text: currentPage.toString() + ' of ' + pageCount, alignment: 'center'
                    }
                  ]
                };
              },
              pageSize: 'A4',
              pageMargins: [40, 80, 40, 60],
              content: [
                { text: companyName, style: 'header', alignment: 'center' },
                { lineHeight: 2, text: 'Pay Slip', fontSize: 15, alignment: 'center' },
                { lineHeight: 2, text: 'Pay Period: 01 ' + monthNameS + ' ' + year + ' - ' + day + ' ' + monthNameS + ' ' + year , fontSize: 12, alignment: 'center', bold: true },
                { text: 'Employee Information', style: 'subheader'},
                {
                  columns: [
                    {
                      width: 120,
                      fontSize: 10,
                      text: 'Employee Name\n' +
                            'Employee ID\n' +
                            'Employee Type\n'+
                            'Designation'
                    },
                    {
                      width: 155,
                      fontSize: 10,
                      text: ':  ' + employeeName + '\n' +
                            ':  ' + employeeId + '\n' +
                            ':  ' + employeeType + '\n' +
                            ':  ' + employeeDesignation + '\n'
                    },
                    {
                      width: 120,
                      fontSize: 10,
                      text: 'Department\n' +
                            'Join Date\n' +
                            'Weekends\n' +
                            'Shift'
                    },
                    {
                      width: 155,
                      fontSize: 10,
                      text: ':  ' + employeeDepartment + '\n' +
                            ':  ' + employeeJoinDate + '\n' +
                            ':  ' + weekends + '\n' +
                            ':  ' + shift + '\n' +
                            '  (Break: '  + breakDuration + 'min)'
                    }
                  ]
                },
                { text: 'Leave Information', style: 'subheader'},
                {
                  columns: [
                    { width: 20, text: '' },
                    table(leaveDataDict, ['Leave Types', 'Leave Entitled(days)', 'Leave Taken(days)', 'Leave Accrued(days)', 'Leave Remained(days)']),
                  ]
                },

                { text: 'Salary Information', style: 'subheader'},
                {
                  style: 'table',
                  table: {
                    body: [
                      ['Basic', 'Overtime', 'Additional', 'Unpaid Leave Deduction', 'Less Work Deduction', 'Total Pay', 'Tax Deduction', 'Net pay'],
                      [basicPay, overtimePay, additionalPay, unpaidLeaveDeduction, lessWorkDeduction, totalPay, taxDeduction, netSalary]
                    ]
                  }
                },
              ],
              styles: {
                header: {
                  fontSize: 18,
                  bold: true,
                  margin: [0, 0, 0, 10]
                },
                subheader: {
                  fontSize: 15,
                  bold: true,
                  margin: [0, 10, 0, 5]
                },
                tableHeader: {
                  bold: true,
                  fontSize: 13,
                  color: 'black'
                },
                table: {
                  fontSize: 9,
                  margin: [0, 5, 0, 15]
                },
              },
            }
            pdfFilename = 'Payslip-' + employeeName + '-' + monthNameS + year + '.pdf'
              // pdfMake.createPdf(docDefinition).download('Payslip-' + employeeName + '-' + monthNameS + year, window);
              pdfMake.createPdf(docDefinition).getBase64(function(data) {
                zip.file(pdfFilename, data);
                // var content = zip.generate();
                // location.href="data:application/zip;base64,"+content;
              });
          }
          console.log(zip);
          var content = zip.generate();
          location.href="data:application/zip;base64,"+content;
          
        }
      });
    }
```

this is my code. I am looping over all the data to generate multiple pdf. Then passing the pdfs to jsZIP. but all the time zip file is returning empty.

Is this the right way to download multiple pdf in jsZIP?

Comment: Did you ever find a solution to this issue fahim?

Comment: yes i did. do you need any help?

Comment: Figured it out last night at 4am, thanks though!

Comment: Hi @fahimirfan I am facing the same issue and unable to figure out. I think it has to do something with async method calls. Can you please post your solution .. Thanks.